# Django - Creating a link that maps to multiple different pages?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to create a link using Django (if possible) that sends the user to three different urls with equal probability of being to redirected to each one. Thus there is only one button to select but it can have three different results.

I would like the link to simply be a bootstrap nav bar button. So far I have the following code that works just fine for a single basic html (surprise.html) url that I created:

Relevant code in:

Views:

```
def surprise(request):
    return render(request, 'sitepages/surprise.html')
```

Templates:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'surprise' %}">Surprise</a>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^surprise/', sitepages.views.surprise, name="surprise"),
```

So this will redirect to a basic internal html page. But I was wondering if it's possible to add another href to the template code?

Perhaps a new model would be necessary? I was thinking of using random.choice with three different urls in the list but it seems they need to be in str type and this is beyond me.

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank You!

Comment: are the **three urls that send the user to three different urls** in your project, where are these three urls?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Currently I have created 3 different urls that sit within sitepages/templates/sitepages as simple html files. Sitepages is the name of the app. I have theoretically connected them via views.py and urls.py, but for the purpose of this task they could be any urls. They can be 3 external links for example 1.href=http://www.google.com     2.href=http://www.yahoo.com    3.href=http://www.blanck.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a custom templatetag or randomize the url in the view before template rendering and passing it to a template via context. Here's the solution using templatetag:

app_name/templatetags/util_tags.py (keep in mind to add `__init__.py` file)

```
import random 
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def random_url():
    list_of_route_names = ['view1', 'view2', 'view3'] # names from urls.py
    return reverse(random.choice(list_of_route_names))
```

template.html:

```
{% load util_tags %}
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% random_url %}">Surprise</a>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^view1/', sitepages.views.view1, name="view1"),
url(r'^view2/', sitepages.views.view2, name="view2"),
url(r'^view3/', sitepages.views.view3, name="view3"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I feel I am close but I am getting an
'random_url' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'format_string'
error message. 
I created the _init__.py file within the templatetags folder and I have 3 basic view.html pages set up and connected via urls.py and views.py as suggested.

Comment: I got it to work. I removed the format_string input from `def random_url(format_string):`
Then I imported sitepages.views into util_tags.py. This connected everything together and the button works as desired. There is an equal random chance of being sent to one of three pages. Thank you again for the function code!

Comment: yes sorry, that was my bad. Updating the original answer